# JavaFX. Как получить Stage на этапе инициализации контроллера

Tags: java, javafx

```
 @FXML
 private AnchorPane anchorPane;

 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
        windowManager = new WindowManager(currentStage);
 }
```

В этом случае возникает NullPointerException, поскольку AnchorPane еще не загружен. Я конечно могу получить объект и не на этапе инициализации, но мне нужно создать экземпляр некого WindowManager с передачей Stage в конструктор, и желательно это сделать сразу, чем я потом буду в каждый метод добавлять проверку на то, не создан ли у меня уже WindowManager.

Вообщем, возможно есть интерфейс типа Initializable, выполняющийся после инициализации, или может можно получить Stage как-то по другому?

Answer (score 0):

Придумал довольно интересное решение своей проблемы: в конструктор WindowManager можно передать реализацию функционального интерфейса Supplier. Таким образом мы получаем возможность вызова объекта Stage тогда, когда он уже будет доступен.

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPane;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    windowManager = new WindowManager(() -> (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow());
}
```